# Find the percentual change in density of a cylinder when it's temperature is increased

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, thermal-conductivity, heat-conduction

When the temperature of a metal cylinder is raised from $0.0°C$ to $100°C$, its length increases by $0.23\%$. Find the percent change in density.

This is the question 18.16 from (David Halliday's "Fundamentals of Physics", 10th ed.)

The Instructors Solutions Manual gives the following solution:

$$\rho = \frac{m}{V}$$
$$\Delta \rho = \Delta(\frac m V)$$
$$\Delta \rho=m\Delta (\frac 1 V)$$
$$\Delta \rho \simeq -m\frac{\Delta V}{V^2}$$
$$\Delta \rho = -\rho (\frac{\Delta V}{V})$$
$$\Delta \rho = -3\rho (\frac{\Delta L}{L})$$
$$\frac{\Delta \rho}{\rho} = -3\frac{\Delta L}{L}$$
$$\frac{\Delta \rho}{\rho} = -3(0.23\%)$$
$$\frac{\Delta \rho}{\rho} = -0.69\%$$
What I don't understand is what was done from line 3 to 4. What physical argument or formula was used there?

Comment: A [Taylor series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) of small $\Delta(1/V)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He took a derivative.

$$d\left(\frac{1}{V}\right) = -\frac{1}{V^2} dV
$$

The reason he uses an "approximately equal" symbol is that he is approximating a difference $\Delta$ with a derivative, which is an infinitesimal difference. The approximation works if the difference $\Delta V$ is very small (relative to $V$).

Comment: And for what reason he multiplied all by $\Delta  V$?

Comment: That's the $dV$ part of the derivative that I had left out of my answer.  I corrected it.